# Is there a way to use do.call without explicitly providing arguments

Tags: r

Part of a custom function I am trying to create allows the user to provide a function as a parameter.  For example

```
#Custom function
result <- function(.func){
  do.call(.func, list(x,y))
}

#Data
x <- 1:2
y <- 0:1

#Call function
result(.func = function(x,y){ sum(x, y) })
```

However, the code above assumes that the user is providing a function with arguments x and y.  Is there  a way to use do.call (or something similar) so that the user can provide a function with different arguments?  I think that the correct solution might be along the lines of:

```
#Custom function
result <- function(.func){
  do.call(.func, formals(.func))
}

#Data
m <- 1:3
n <- 0:2
x <- 1:2
y <- 0:1
z <- c(4,6)

#Call function
result(.func = function(m,n){ sum(m, n) })
result(.func = function(x,y,z){ sum(x,y,z) })
```

But this is not it.

Comment: The function I'm trying to create will pass in a dataframe and then do computations on the dataframe based on the specified .func and do.call will refer to column names.

Comment: I won't actually be using sum.  The main point is that I don't want to have to specify list(x,y) explicitly in do.call because the functin specified in .func will sometimes have more parameters, sometimes have less parameters, and sometimes have parameters with names other than x and y.

Comment: If I can get it to work in the above example then I can get it to work in the situation I want to use it in.  I'm really only concerned with changing the do.call(.func, list(x,y)) line in the first code block (which explicitly defines parameters as x and y) to something more general where the user can define their own parameters when calling the result function.  So in the second code block, list(x,y) was replaced with something that attempts to get the parameters defined in .func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Use formals/names/mget to get the values in a list.  An optional argument, `envir`, will allow the user to specify the environment that the variables are located in so it knows where to look.  The default if not specified is the parent frame, i.e. the caller.

```
result1 <- function(.func, envir = parent.frame()) {
  do.call(.func, mget(names(formals(.func)), envir))
}

m <- 1:3
n <- 0:2
x <- 1:2
y <- 0:1
z <- c(4,6)

result1(.func = function(m,n) sum(m, n) )
## [1] 9

result1(.func = function(x,y,z) sum(x,y,z) )
## [1] 14

result1(function(Time, demand) Time + demand, list2env(BOD))
## [1]  9.3 12.3 22.0 20.0 20.6 26.8
```

**1a)** Another possibility is to evaluate the body.  This also works if envir is specified as a data frame whose columns are to be looked up.

```
result1a <- function(.func, envir = parent.frame()) {
  eval(body(.func), envir)
}

result1a(.func = function(m,n) sum(m, n) )
## [1] 9

result1a(.func = function(x,y,z) sum(x,y,z) )
## [1] 14

result1a(function(Time, demand) Time + demand, BOD)
## [1]  9.3 12.3 22.0 20.0 20.6 26.8
```

**2)** Another design which is even simpler is to provide a one-sided formula interface.  Formulas have environments so we can use that to look up the variables.

```
result2 <- function(fo, envir = environment(fo)) eval(fo[[2]], envir)

result2(~ sum(m, n))
## [1] 9

result2(~ sum(x,y,z))
## [1] 14

result2(~ Time + demand, BOD)
## [1]  9.3 12.3 22.0 20.0 20.6 26.8
```

**3)** Even simpler yet is to just pass the result of the computation as an argument.

```
result3 <- function(x) x

result3(sum(m, n))
## [1] 9

result3(sum(x,y,z))
## [1] 14

result3(with(BOD, Time + demand))
## [1]  9.3 12.3 22.0 20.0 20.6 26.8
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
#Custom function
result <- function(.func){
  do.call(.func, lapply(formalArgs(.func), as.name))
}

#Data
m <- 1:3
n <- 0:2
x <- 1:2
y <- 0:1
z <- c(4,6)

#Call function
result(.func = function(m,n){ sum(m, n) })
result(.func = function(x,y,z){ sum(x,y,z) })
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bit of a pointless function, since the examples in your question imply that what you are trying to do is evaluate the body of the passed function using variables in the calling environment. You can certainly do this easily enough:

```r
result <- function(.func){
  eval(body(.func), envir = parent.frame())
}
```

This gives the expected results from your examples:

```r
x <- 1:2
y <- 0:1

result(.func = function(x,y){ sum(x, y) })
#> [1] 4
```

and

```r
m <- 1:3
n <- 0:2
x <- 1:2
y <- 0:1
z <- c(4,6)

result(.func = function(m,n){ sum(m, n) })
#> [1] 9
result(.func = function(x,y,z){ sum(x,y,z) })
#> [1] 14
```

But note that, when the user types:

```r
result(.func = function(x,y){ ...user code... })
```

They get the same result they would already get if they didn't use your function and simply typed

```r
...user code....
```

You could argue that it would be helpful with a pre-existing function like `mean.default`:

```r
x <- 1:10
na.rm <- TRUE
trim <- 0
result(mean.default)
#> [1] 5.5
```

But this means users have to name their variables as the parameters being passed to the function, and this is just a less convenient way of calling the function.

It might be useful if you could demonstrate a use case where what you are proposing doesn't make the user's code longer or more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `...`, but like the other responses, I don't quite see the value, or perhaps I don't fully understand the use-case.

```
result <- function(.func, ...){
  do.call(.func, list(...))
}
```

Create function

```
f1 <- function(a,b) sum(a,b)
```

Pass `f1` and values to `result()`

```
result(f1, m,n)
```

Output:

```
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it based on your clarifying comments.

Basically since you say your function will take a data.frame as input, the function you are asking for essentially just reverses the order of arguments you pass to `do.call()`... which takes a function, then a list of arguments. A data.frame is just a special form of list where all elements (columns) are vectors of equal length (number of rows)

```r
result <- function(.data, .func) {
  # .data is a data.frame, which is a list of argument vectors of equal length
  do.call(.func, .data)
}
result(data.frame(a=1, b=1:5), function(a, b) a * b)

result(data.frame(c=1:10, d=1:10), function(c, d) c * d)
```

Comment: If it is ok to have the function first and then the data we could write this as `result <- do.call`